# Fastest way to interleave RGB channels (from [R, R, G, G, B, B] to [R, G, B, R, G, B]) in Rust

Tags: rust

I've been stuck on trying to find a faster way to interleave the contents of a vector with data in the form [R,R,R,...,G,G,G,...,B,B,B,...] to [R,G,B,R,G,B,R,G,B,...]. Currently I have this code which takes around 60-200ms to run for vectors of size (1024*1024*3) but I need this to be in the 10ms range if possible. I've tried some functional methods but unless I'm doing something very wrong they increased the time to 500-700ms.

```rust
static TILE_LENGTH: usize = 1024 * 1024;

let channels = vec![0; TILE_LENGTH * 3];

let mut tile = Vec::with_capacity(TILE_LENGTH * 3);
for i in 0..TILE_LENGTH {
    tile.push(channels[i]);
    tile.push(channels[i + (TILE_LENGTH)]);
    tile.push(channels[i + (TILE_LENGTH * 2)]);
}
```

Comment: Did you run with `--release`?

Comment: Also what type are the items?

Comment: Ok you're right I completely forgot. I didn't realise it would make such a big difference. Now I'm down to around 10-20ms which is perfect thanks. Just out of curiosity, there aren't any other obviously faster ways right? Also they're just u8 values. Its raw image data with every element representing the channel value so 0 to 255 for each of R, G and B. @drewtato

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I did was recreate your code.

```rust
pub fn plain_index<'a>(channels: &[u8], tile: &'a mut Vec<u8>) -> &'a [u8] {
    tile.clear();
    tile.reserve(channels.len());

    let len_each = channels.len() / 3;

    for i in 0..len_each {
        tile.push(channels[i]);
        tile.push(channels[i + len_each]);
        tile.push(channels[i + len_each * 2]);
    }

    tile
}
```

I've moved both `Vec` allocations outside the function. If your program only needs to call this function once, it doesn't matter, but if you need to call it many times, you can reuse the buffer, which saves a lot of time. This one ran in **32ms**. Remember to run with `--release` when judging performance.

Then, I made some alternative versions and ended up with this one.

```rust
pub fn zip_extend<'a>(channels: &[u8], tile: &'a mut Vec<u8>) -> &'a [u8] {
    tile.clear();
    tile.reserve(channels.len());

    let len_each = channels.len() / 3;
    let rs = &channels[..len_each];
    let gs = &channels[len_each..len_each * 2];
    let bs = &channels[len_each * 2..];

    tile.extend(
        rs.iter()
            .zip(gs)
            .zip(bs)
            .flat_map(|((&r, &g), &b)| [r, g, b]),
    );
    
    tile
}
```

First, why it should be fast:

- The channels are split up immediately. The compiler will be able to tell that these advance forward independently.
- `extend` can write all items before updating the length of the `Vec`.
- Iterators over slices tend to optimize well.

And it is! It runs in **5.2ms**.

I also tried Rayon, but it's not the cleanest. This task isn't great for parallelization since it's so fast already. I also couldn't find an existing Rayon API to make this work in safe code, so I've unsafely edited the `Vec`.

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

pub fn par_zip_spare_arr<'a>(channels: &[u8], tile: &'a mut Vec<u8>) -> &'a [u8] {
    tile.clear();
    tile.reserve(channels.len());
    let spare = tile.spare_capacity_mut();

    let len_each = channels.len() / 3;
    let rs = &channels[..len_each];
    let gs = &channels[len_each..len_each * 2];
    let bs = &channels[len_each * 2..];

    (spare.par_chunks_exact_mut(3), rs, gs, bs)
        .into_par_iter()
        .for_each(|(spare, &r, &g, &b)| {
            let spare: &mut [MaybeUninit<u8>; 3] = spare.try_into().unwrap();
            *spare = [r, g, b].map(MaybeUninit::new);
        });

    // SAFETY: all the elements were written in the previous loop
    unsafe { tile.set_len(len_each * 3) }
    tile
}
```

This runs in **1.9ms**, but will depend on how many cores you have, and of course if you are already occupying the cores with other things, this won't help.

The last thing I did was [change the build configuration](https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/build-configuration.html#cpu-specific-instructions). If you add `-C target-cpu=native` to the compiler flags, instead of generating assembly that works on any CPU with your CPU architecture, it will generate the best assembly it can for your specific CPU. In this case, my CPU supports AVX2, which is common for newer x86_64 CPUs. I reran the benchmarks and found my first function, `zip_extend`, now runs in **1.5ms**. The rest were not noticeably affected.

There's tons of other things you can try in the [Performance Book](https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/introduction.html).

Comment: `native` is a bit of a hamfisted approach, but does hint at a core problem: the _default_ setup for x64 are the first x64 CPUs released, which had much less instructions. One can bump the instruction set (SSE4.2, AVX, AVX512) based on one's target machines and reap the rewards accordingly.

Comment: Interesting, this definitely runs faster by at least 10x in my code. The "tile" vector passed into the function doesn't live long after the interleaving step, so is clear and reserve here doing anything? Or do they hint to the rust compiler to keep a buffer allocated to the function for future use? Also is there a reason you chose to do channels.len() over the static variables. Given that I know 100% the length of the vector, do I get any performance benefits for using a static variable. Anyways thanks for the help. And yeah rayon is overkill, this is already running in a thread lasting <30ms.

Comment: I only did `len` so I could test different buffer lengths. You sometimes get better performance from hardcoding the length, so worth a try.